# Given $y=(x+1)^{6x}$ use logarithmic differentiation to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The final answer I got after working this is $\frac{6(x+1)^{6x}}{x+1}$.

But I am not confident in my answer. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking natural logs of both sides then implicitly differentiating, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
\ln y &= \ln((x+1)^{6x}) \\
\ln y &= 6x\ln(x+1) \\
\frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} &= 6x \cdot \frac{1}{x+1} + 6 \cdot \ln(x+1) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= y\left[\frac{6x}{x+1} + 6\ln(x+1)\right] \\
\frac{dy}{dx} &= (x+1)^{6x}\left[\frac{6x}{x+1} + 6\ln(x+1)\right]
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Let $y = (x+1)^{6x} $. Take $ln$ in both sides,  we have

$$ \ln y = 6x \ln (x+1) \iff \frac{y'}{y} = 6 \ln(x+1) + \frac{6x}{x+1} \iff y' = ....$$